# Silverlight 5 double-click always returns ClickCount as 1

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I created behavior for DataGrid to detect double-click:

```
public class DataGridDoubleClickBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>    
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CommandParameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(DataGridDoubleClickBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));        

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }            
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleClickCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DoubleClickCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(DataGridDoubleClickBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));       

        public ICommand DoubleClickCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty); }            
            set { SetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.LoadingRow += this.OnLoadingRow;
            this.AssociatedObject.UnloadingRow += this.OnUnloadingRow;

            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.LoadingRow -= this.OnLoadingRow;
            this.AssociatedObject.UnloadingRow -= this.OnUnloadingRow;

            base.OnDetaching();
        } 

        private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.MouseLeftButtonUp += this.OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void OnUnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.MouseLeftButtonUp -= this.OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickCount < 2) return;

            if (this.DoubleClickCommand != null) this.DoubleClickCommand.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to be fine except that it doesn't register multiple clicks. In `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` ClickCount always 1. Does anybody know why?

Comment: As a couple of sanity checks, maybe run Pete's sample to validate that it works and/or run one of the existing SL4 DataGrid+DoubleClick projects like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115405/Double-Click-DataGrid-in-Silverlight ?

Comment: What I'm doing is part of SL5 upgrade. Getting rid of code like that since multi-click actually "supported"... I have working code. I just want to make it right.

Answer (score 11):

I found a very simple solution. Just replace the event handler registration syntax

```
myDataGrid.MouseLeftButtonDown += this.MyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

with the `AddHandler` syntax

```
myDataGrid.AddHandler(DataGrid.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(this.MyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown),
    handledEventsToo: true)
```

That way the magic boolean `handledEventsToo` argument can be specified.

This will, well, handle handled events too.

Comment: This works nicely :-) Then use interactivity stuff to get the event up to the VM and you're gold

Comment: Worked for me and gave +1. You don't have to have the `handledEventsToo:` in there though but I guess it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: it's good practice for method calls when arguments are specified with literals like *true* or *42* instead of descriptive variables. Makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the bigger trouble here is that when you click on the rows of a DataGrid, MouseLeftButtonDown is not raised, because this click is being handled at the row level.

I've long given up on dealing with some controls directly. I've my own derived version of the DataGrid, DataForm and etc. This only makes my solution easy to roll out, because I don't use the vanilla versions anyway.

I added a new event called ClickIncludingHandled, it's a bit wordy but it properly describes what's going on and will nicely appear right below Click with IntelliSense - if the control has a Click event to begin with.

Anyway, below is my implementation of it. You can then subscribe to this event and use ClickCount to determine the number of clicks you want to capture. I noticed it is a bit slow, but it works cleanly.

```
public partial class DataGridBase : DataGrid
{
        public event MouseButtonEventHandler ClickIncludingHandled;

        public DataGridBase() : base()
        {
            this.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnClickInclHandled), true);
        }

        private void OnClickInclHandled(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ClickIncludingHandled != null)
            {
                ClickIncludingHandled(sender, e);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MouseButtonUp is broken with respect to capturing ClickCount in WPF and Silverlight (it's been recorded many times but Microsoft has opted not to fix it). You need to use MouseButtonDown events.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is the issue, but I notice that Pete Brown's sample uses MouseLeftButtonDown instead:

http://10rem.net/blog/2011/04/13/silverlight-5-supporting-double-and-even-triple-click-for-the-mouse

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem. I couldn't manage to resolve it in any sensible way, so worked around it like this:

```
    private DateTime _lastClickTime;
    private WeakReference _lastSender;

    private void Row_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if ((now - _lastClickTime).TotalMilliseconds < 200 && _lastSender != null && _lastSender.IsAlive && _lastSender.Target == sender)
        {
            if (Command != null)
            {
                Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
            }
        }
        _lastClickTime = now;
        _lastSender = new WeakReference(sender);
    }
```

It's dirty but it works.

Comment: Technically, should use SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime, and check that each click is within the SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize

Comment: The SystemInformation class is in System.Windows.Forms, and thus isn't available in Silverlight.